# PDF content returned in web response, how to save locally?

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, webclient

I'm getting a web response via an API which converts file (in this case, Powerpoint presentations to PDF).

I do get the response in a string, but when saving this string to a file or a stream (which ends up being saved in a file anyways) I always end up with a blank file, its size is always well over 0 bytes though.

Here's the class that calls the API:

```
public class CloudConvert
{

    private string apiKey;
    private static object ProcessResponse;

    public CloudConvert(string apiKey)
    {
        this.apiKey = apiKey;
    }

    public async Task<string> Convert(string inputFormat, string outputFormat, string fileUrl)
    {
        var processUrl = await CreateProcess(inputFormat, outputFormat);
        return await Upload(processUrl, fileUrl, outputFormat);
    }

    private async Task<string> CreateProcess(string inputFormat, string outputFormat)
    {
        var request = new
        {
            apikey = apiKey,
            inputformat = inputFormat,
            outputformat = outputFormat
        };

        var json = await PostJson("https://api.cloudconvert.com/process", request);

        dynamic obj = JObject.Parse(json);
        ProcessResponse = obj;
        return "https:" + obj.url;
    }

    private static async Task<string> Upload(string processUrl,
        string fileUrl, string outputFormat)
    {
        var request = new
        {
            input = "download",
            file = fileUrl,
            outputformat = outputFormat,
            download = "false",
            wait = "true",
            save = "false"
        };

        return await PostJson(processUrl, request);
    }


    private static async Task<string> PostJson(string url, object data)
    {
        var parameters = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

        using (var wc = new WebClient())
        {
            wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";

            try
            {
                return await wc.UploadStringTaskAsync(url, "POST", parameters);
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And how I'm invoking it:

```
Task<string> task = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    return await cloudConvert.Convert("ppt", "pdf", "http://host.com/myfile.ppt");
});

//I have the PDF in the response, as a string.
var pdfContent = task.Result;

//I think it's here that I'm not handling the resulting string 
//properly, ending in a blank file. I've tried writing it to a local file as well, same issue.
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
    writer.Write(pdfContent);
    writer.Flush();
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    //This below is something that saves to an Azure storage container...
    //filePath = fileStorage.SaveFile($"{fileGeneratedName}.pdf", stream);

    //But this fails as well. Blank file 
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\tmp\output.pdf", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
    {
        stream.CopyTo(fs);
        fs.Flush();
    }
}
```

So regardless of how I'm trying to save the returned content, it seems my encoding is wrong. I noticed that the resulting blank file always has the same number of pages than the input Powerpoint presentation.

Any ideas?

Comment: PDF are binary files and can't be represented by strings. Or you are receiving the content with the incorrect format (string instead of binary) or the returned data is encoded in base64. Refer to the service documentation to know the problem.

Comment: @Gusman `pdfContent` does seem to hold data similar to data I would see if I would open a working PDF in Notepad++. (`%PDF-1.7` header for example).

Comment: Then you are reading it as string and that's incorrect, you must read it as binary data or you will corrupt the content.

Answer (score 0):

Have your convert function return an HttpResponseMessage:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> convert()
```

do your conversion into, say, a memory stream, and then:

```
var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
     Content = new ByteArrayContent(outStream.GetBuffer(),0,(int)outStream.Length)
};
result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition =
         new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
         {
              FileName = fname
         };
result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
return result;
```